# GeoServer WFS can't return results in GeoJSON format

Tags: geoserver, geojson, wfs

I am creating GeoReport in SpagoBI using GeoServer.
In my GeoServer I created workspace, layer, and store. Everything works fine there. Now I am creating the report template, which is simple .json file.
I need to put there the url, it is the url of the wfs to call in order to obtain features contained in the target layer, the wfs mus be able to return results in geojson format. 
My url looks like this

```
targetLayerConf: {  
    text: 'Ethio'  
    , name: 'Eth_Region_2013'  
    , url: 'http://localhost:8090/geoserver/wfs'    

},
```

When i put this url into my web browser it should return geojson as well. But 
instead of this, I got an error, like this:

```
This XML file does not appear to have any style information associated with it. The document tree is shown below.
<ows:ExceptionReport xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:ows="http://www.opengis.net/ows/1.1" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" version="2.0.0" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.opengis.net/ows/1.1 http://localhost:8090/geoserver/schemas/ows/1.1.0/owsAll.xsd">
<ows:Exception exceptionCode="MissingParameterValue" locator="request">
<ows:ExceptionText>
Could not determine geoserver request from http request org.geoserver.platform.AdvancedDispatchFilter$AdvancedDispatchHttpRequest@48c82d5d
</ows:ExceptionText>
</ows:Exception>
</ows:ExceptionReport>
```

The URL is correct I guess. I think it can be problem in the GeoServer settings.

Comment: `SpagoBI geo report manual. There Is not much about GetFeature parameter` except it does say:  _If you are using GeoServer you can easily obtain a GeoJSON layer invoking a WFS with an url like this:
http://:/geoserver/it.geodemo/ows?service=WFS&version=1.0.0&request=GetFeature&typeName=&outputFormat=json

After this operation, you are able to save the service response in a .json file under the /resources/georeport directory and use it in offline mode (or rather without calling the GeoServer WFS system_

Answer (score 1):

Please read the error message:

```
<ows:Exception exceptionCode="MissingParameterValue" locator="request">
```

You did not specify `request=GetFeature` (at least) in your URL.

I can't find a manual for SpagoBI but if you have one it will probably describe how to create a valid GetFeature request and specify the return format (hint try `outputFormat=json`)

Comment: http://wiki.spagobi.org/xwiki/bin/view/spagobi_server/GeoReport here is the SpagoBI geo report manual. There Is not much about GetFeature  parameter

Answer (score 1):

The error indicates that GeoServer has been called without the necessary minimum parameters, e.g., service, request, feature type and the like.

Compare this, failing in the same way:

http://demo.geo-solutions.it/geoserver/wfs

with a valid request returning GeoJSON:

http://demo.geo-solutions.it/geoserver/wfs?service=WFS&version=1.0.0&request=GetFeature&typeName=tiger:giant_polygon&outputFormat=JSON